# Add groups of numbers every nth number in an array - iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, arrays

I know my question may not be very clear so I will try to explain as best as I can. I have an array `array1` which has a number of doubles in it. I would like, every nth number, combine those "n" numbers (by adding) into a single double and maybe even add that to it's own array `array2`
Example:

```
1\
2 \
3  \
4   > (1 + 2 + 3...) <--object 0 in `array2`
5  /
6 /
7/
8 \
9  \
10  \
11   > (8 + 9 + 10...) <--object 1 in `array2`
12  /
13 /
14/
```

The nth number in the above sequence would be seven. I'm thinking I would have to separate the array into smaller ones every seven numbers. Would this be possible? Please give any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Logic:
array1= array with elements
array2= array in which combined results will be saved
float fResult=0;

int i=0;
while(i<array1.count)
{
for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
{ 
  if(i>=array1.count)
 {
 break;
 } 

   if(j==0)
  {
   fResult=0;
  }

   fResult=fResult+[[array1 objectAtIndex:i]floatValue];
   i++;

   if(j==n-1 || i==array1.count)
   {
    [array2 addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:fResult]];
   }

}
}
```

Here n is the number of elements to be combined in one element. In your case its 7.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I get an error at `fResult = fResult + [array1 objectAtIndex:1];`
invalid operands to binary expression ('float' and 'id')

Comment: I gave logic only. You will have to save float in NSArray using '[NSNumber NuberWithFloat:]` and get back the float value using `[NSNumber floatValue]`

Comment: Sorry I'm confused as to what you're saying. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I'm getting a SIGABRT error that says uncaught exception. objectAtIndex: index 10 exceed index (0...9). I don't know why though because it shouldn't exceed the count. Also in your answer, you seem to be missing the if-statement brackets so it's hard to tell what's in them and what's not.

Comment: I've not added brackets to if because it doesn't need there...It should only execute the line just bellow it if condition is met. Hope I am understandable. It sholdn't crash I think

Comment: This will crash when array1.count is not a multiple of n

Comment: Thanks for pointing! Silly mistake..Edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I just put logic;

```
MainArray;
array1;
array2;
int n = 7;
int loopNumber = ceil(MainArray/n);

for(int k = 0; k < loopNumber ; k ++)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < n ; i ++)
   {
       if(k == 0)
         [array1 addObject:[MainArray objectAtIndex:i]];
       if(k == 1)
         [array2 addObject:[MainArray objectAtIndex:i]];

   } 
}
```

Comment: That won't work! You'll never access the `MainArray` on index higher than `n-1` and you're also not adding any numbers up.